# Magento static block for category showing the subcategories with thumbnails

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I'm creating a static block to show the subcategories of a category in Magento. The code is made by me and with some ideas taken in the web.
The idea is to show a title with plain background called back.png as thumbnail of the subcategory when this one hasn't a thumbnail or the category thumbnail if the image is uploaded. For the moment I can't show the thumbnails, could anybody help me?
Thanks.

```
<div class="product_list" style="width:900px;">
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if($currentCategory->children_count > 0) { ?>
<?php
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategory->entity_id);
    $_categories = $cat->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($_categories as $_category):  //print_r($_category); ?>
<?php
    $imageUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getThumbnailUrl();

    $imageName = substr(strrchr($imageUrl,"/"),1);
    $imagePrefx = Mage::getBaseUrl('media')."catalog/category/";
    $newImageUrl2 = $imagePrefx.$imageName;
?><div clas="subcat-el">

<li style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
<div class="subcat-name" style="z-index:20; width:270px; position:absolute; margin-top:134px;text-align: center;">
    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>" style="text-decoration:none;">
    <h3 style="margin-left:18px; font-family:Helvetica; font-weight:200;text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #030;font-size: 24px;color:#fff; ">

            <?php echo $_category->getName()            ?>
    </h3>       
        </a> 

    </div>
    <div style="width:270px; height:270px;background: #fff;
                border: 9px solid #fff; border-radius: 3px;-webkit-border-radius: 3px;-moz-border-radius: 3px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);margin-bottom:10px;">
    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
        <img src="<?php 
        if ($newImageUrl2 == $imagePrefx): $newImageUrl2 = Mage::getBaseUrl('skin')."/subcat/back.png";
        endif;
        echo $newImageUrl2; ?>" alt="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>" style="width:100%;">
    </a>

    </div>  
</li>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<br style="clear:left;" />
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php } else { echo "<h3>No Sub-category found</h3>"; } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method by default as in your line:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getThumbnailUrl();
```

you should try `getThumbnail()` instead

Or you could try smth like this

```
$imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/category/' . $_category->getThumbnail()
```

Or you can try to specify your own method getThumbnailUrl in your own extension

```
public function getThumbnailUrl(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category)
{
    return (bool)$category->getThumbnail()
        ? Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/category/' . $category->getThumbnail()
        : '';
}
```